# How do I do this triple integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I have to find the volume of the region in the first octant $(x\ge0,y\ge0,z\ge0$ bounded by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ and the planes $z=2$ and $y+z=4$. 
I’m trying to evaluate the following integral to get the volume —
$\int_0^2$ $\int_0^{4-z}$ $\int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}$ $dx dy dz$

If I’m correct about the above, its evaluation is quite complicated...
Is there an easier way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Between those two planes $z\ge2$. Rethink the ranges.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a picture. I forgot to label the axes, but I'm sure you can figure out which is which :-)

Comment: @user733666:  The slanted plane is irrelevant and always outside the region defined by $z=2$.  Delete it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm fairly sure the question is about the intersection of the quarter cylinder and that wedge formed be the two planes. Its volume is a straightforward integral
$$V=\int_{z=2}^4\int_{y=0}^{4-z}\sqrt{4-y^2}\,dy\,dz.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^2 \int\limits_{y=0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int\limits_{z=2}^{4-y}\ 1\ dx\ dy\ dz = 2 \pi -\frac{8}{3}$$

Comment: Inside the cylinder $y\le2$, so the minimum is obvious. I think this is not the intended region because the plane $y+z=4$ does not come into play at all.

Comment: $z=2$ is the *bottom* border. On the upper border we have $y+z=4$.